# ng-click won't trigger in ui-grid columnDef template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to trigger a custom function inside of my columnDef cell template as follows:

```
export class GridComponent {
   constructor() {}

   this.gridOptions = {
       // grid options defined here
       columnDef.cellTemplate = '<bss-cell cellval="{{row.entity[col.name]}}"></bss-cell>';
   }

   private cellClicked () {
        // need to get the click event here but can't
        console.log('got here');
   }
}
```

This column definition holds the data in my grid. Bss Cell is a custom angular component I made which looks like this:

```
//BSS CELL CONTROLLER CODE FOR THE COLUMN DEF CELL TEMPLATE

import * as angular from 'angular';
import '../../../../modules/bss/bss.component';

export class TreeCellComponent {

    constructor() {
    }

    private cellClicked () {
        // click event does come here if I call $ctrl.cellClicked() from my template but this isn't connected to the grid
    }
}


angular.module('app.modules.uigridtemplates.bss-cell', ['app.modules.bss'])
.component('bssCell', {
    bindings: {
        cellval: '@'
    },
    controller: TreeCellComponent,
    template: require('./bss-cell.html')
});


// BSS CELL DIRECTIVE TEMPLATE
<div ng-click="grid.AppScope.cellClicked()" align="right" class="ui-grid-cell-contents-data-grid" title="
      {{$ctrl.cellval}}">
      <span>{{$ctrl.cellval}}</span>
</div>
```

How can I get that click to take place so that it runs to the "cellClicked" function inside of my GridComponent, which would then allow me to affect the grid the way I would like.

```
 this.cellTemplates = ['uiGridTreeCellTemplate.html', 'uiGridTreeColumnHeaderTemplate.html'];

 this.gridOptions = {
    appScopeProvider: this  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `gridOptions` add this:

```
 appScopeProvider: {
     cellClicked: this.cellClicked
 }
```

In this way in you `grid.appScope` you will find the `cellClicked` function available.

If you have selectable rows, which perform an action when you select one of your rows, I suggest to pass the `$event` to your `grid.appScope.cellClicked()` function, then in your `appScopeProvider` stop the click event, something like this:

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.cellClicked($event)"
```

and then

```
appScopeProvider: {
    cellClicked: (event) => {
        this.cellClicked();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated my initial post to show you what I currently have for appScopeProvider inside my gridOptions. This allows me to use "grid.AppScope.somefunction()" in my this.templates to call a function in my GridComponent. But calling grid.AppScope doesn't work on the bssCell as it is not a template passed to the grid but a separate angular component. How can I update appScopeProvider to work with this? Thanks again